# chrome not reachable on travis ci

Tags: selenium, travis-ci, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I am trying to use chrome standalone driver on Travis CI server. I am getting this error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'chrome not reachable\`

The script runs fine locally.

in .travis.yml I have

```
before_script:
  # google chrome standalone driver
  - wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
  - sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin
  - sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

and in my tests I have

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
Chrome()
```

and after a delay I get the error message stated above.

I have tried changing the location of the chrome driver, and explicitly pass the `executable_path` to `Chrome`, but no joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successfully run tests in Travis using headless Chrome.

I've used the following arguments to start chrome:

- no-sandbox
- no-default-browser-check
- no-first-run
- disable-default-apps

The *no-sandbox* argument was the one that bypassed the 'chrome not reachable' error.